# I use gulp . project is on Angular 2. How to delete browser-sync from the project?

Tags: angular

How to delete browser_sync from my Angular 2 project?
I use gulp.
When I deploy the project I don't want browser-sync features working.
As I see browser-sync calls by lite-server.js:

```
'use strict';
/**
* lite-server : Simple server for angular/SPA projects
*
* Simply loads some default browser-sync config that apply to SPAs,
* applies custom config overrides from user's own local `bs-config.{js|json}` file,
* and launches browser-sync.
*/
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');
var config = require('./config-defaults');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you remove these tasks:

```
// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

// or...

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "yourlocal.dev"
    });
});
```

Comment: It's removed. I think I've solved an issue:
in bs-config worte:  

    "ghostMode": false,
     "codeSync": false,